# How to SSH twice from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Is there any easy way to SSH twice from Jenkins?

I need to run few scripts on Server 2, however Server 2 is accessible only from Server  1. I can SSH to Server 1 from Jenkins without any issues, but how do I SSH on to Server 2 subsequently to run my scriptd?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Charan

Comment: How exactly (using which step/plugin) did you connect from Jenkins to Server1?

Comment: I am using ssh plugin to connect to first server

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect to server 1 directly; you instruct `ssh` to use server 1 in order to connect to server 2, using the `-J` option.

```
ssh -J server1 server2 some_command
```